# What's the difference between SIP/XMPP for web conferencing and file-sharing?

Tags: xmpp, sip

I want to setup a personal videoconferencing service for my family, friends and myself. The main problem I have with current options is that they are either closed-source and centralized (GG hangouts, skype) or open-source but not working in corporate environment or in hotels (due to strict firewalling rules and the "Skype is going through, if you want VOIP use that" kind of netadmin reaction).

I have two solutions then. Either setup a STUN/TURN relay server and use XMPP and SIP as I used to, but that would require my friends to setup that too. Or setup a whole VOIP server. 2 solutions come to mind: SIP and XMPP. Though to my knowledge, each of them ultimately uses the (S)RTP/RTCP protocol.

And that's the problem. Out of the specific signaling part used by the two of them, I really can't figure out the difference between them, their typical use case.

Comment: I know SO isn't really about specific software recommendations, but make sure to look at Jitsi and specifically JitMeet if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right in that as far as setting up a video conferencing system XMPP and SIP are  equivalent. They both are signalling only protocols and the media sessions they set up typically use RTP (although they can both be used to set up any kind of session you want but RTP is the norm).

The biggest problem is also going to be the one you mention about getting video streams out of a corporate firewall. Skype overcomes this obstacle by sending it's media over an SSL connection and is thus able to get through firewalls. Theoretically you could do the same with RTP and in the past I once used [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) connections with a SIP client to test some audio calls. My experience wasn't great as the audio was very choppy, assumedly as a result of all the extra packaging that is required to get the high volume of small audio packets from one end to the other. That was nearly a decade ago though so perhaps with the better CPU and bandwidth resources available now it would work better.

Personally I think I'd stick with Skype as it's going to be a big hassle to set up your own system. If you were to go ahead with your own the first option I would try would be [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) combined with openvpn so that if the clients were behind a firewall or had NAT issues they could connect over it.